# Create text mask using Python+PIL or Imagemagick

Tags: python, image, text, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

I need to programmatically create a text mask over a solid colour with the text being transparent.

eg.

[image: cut]

Can this be done with either Imagemagick or the Python imaging library?

This works for the inverse of what I want, so solid text over a transparent background.

`convert -size 720x405 xc:transparent -fill pink -gravity center -pointsize 150 -font font.ttf -draw "text 0,0 CUT" output.png`

I would prefer to use PIL/Pillow if possible.

**UPDATED:**

This is what I have so far...

```
font = ImageFont.truetype('font.ttf', 200, encoding='unic')
bg = Image.new('RGBA', (720, 404), '#0099ff')
mask = Image.new('1', (720, 404))

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
draw.text((0, 0), '#HELLO', font=font, fill='#ffffff')

bg.paste('#00000000', (0, 0), text)
bg.save('text.png', 'PNG')
```

However this throws an error:

`ValueError: unknown color specifier: '#00000000'`

If I set to a valid colour it works as expected so I know I'm close, just can't reference the transparency.

**UPDATED:**

In the end I just created another blank image and used that rather than defining the colour. So:

```
trans = Image.new('RGBA', (720, 404))
bg.paste(trans, (0, 0), mask)
```

Comment: Have you tried PIL with NumPy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is relatively simple in PIL.

Here's a pretty good [PIL reference](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm).

There are many ways to do it - here's one:

1. Create an image with the size and background color you want in RGBA mode.
2. Create a blank image of the same size in mode "1" to be used as a mask
3. Write the text on the mask image using the ImageDraw module
4. Use Image.paste(colour, box, mask) to paste the color (0, 0, 0, 0) everywhere the text exists in the mask.

Comment: Almost there, but '#00000000' seems to throw an error. How else can I set the transparency?

Comment: Oops, try the tuple (0, 0, 0, 0) for the color instead.